# Name for Number of Ancestors/Descendants of Vertex in Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed acyclic graph. For each vertex $v \in V$, define the *ancestors* of $v$ to be the set of vertices $u \in V$ such that there exists a directed path from $u$ to $v$. Similarly, define the *descendants* of $v$ to be the set of vertices $w \in V$ such that there exists a directed path from $v$ to $w$. What are the standard names for the number of ancestors and descendants for a given vertex? (They would be analogous to the indegree and outdegree of a vertex.)

Comment: I like this question. I am not certain there exists standard terminology for these quantities, but I'll be sticking around to find out. I haven't thought enough about it yet, but there might be problems or ambiguities with the _ancestor_ / _descendant_ definitions for particular graphs.

Comment: One potentially amusing observation about these terms: It is entirely possible for one vertex to be both an ancestor and a descendant of another. :) Sort of reminds me of that terrible song "I'm My Own Grandpa."

Comment: Isn't this exactly what indegree and outdegree is? Or what am I missing?

Comment: @naslundx Indegree and outdegree refer specifically to the vertices connected to the vertex in question by a single directed edge. Simon is asking about those connected via paths which may comprise more than one edge.

Comment: @DivergentQueries Oh, now I get it. I misread. Thank you.

Comment: @Divergent Queries Good point. Though the graph I'm working with is acyclic so this wouldn't be a problem. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @DivergentQueries I guess the point of a DAG is that you _can't_ be your own grandpa...

Answer (score 2):

Since no one immediately answered this question, I suspect that there are no standard terms for the number of descendants or the number of ancestors of a given node in a directed acyclic graph (DAG). But remember that the point of writing is just to clearly convey an idea to the reader, so you should feel free to invent terms as you need them, just so long as the terms you invent are sensible. I'll compile a few suggestions for you.

- My first thought is to think of the DAG as a *partially ordered set* (poset). Letting $V$ be the set of nodes of our DAG, we can define a partial ordering $\leq$ on $V$ such that $\forall a,b \in V$, $a \leq b$ if there exists a (potentially empty) path from $a$ to $b$. Then we can sensibly define $a<b$ if $a$ is an ancestor of $b$ (or equivalently if $b$ is a descendant of $a$). Using this we can denote the set of ancestors of a node $x$ as $A_x$ and the set descendants of a node $x$ as $D_x$, where 
  $$
    A_x = \{y \in V \mid y<x\} 
    \qquad 
    D_x = \{y \in V \mid y>x\}\;.
  $$ 
  Then we can represent the number of ancestors and descendants symbolically with this mathematical notation as $|A_x|$ and $|D_x|$.
- Following this line of thought, we can also just expand the notion of indegree and outdegree. Let $G$ be a DAG with the partial ordering defined above. Let $G'$ be the DAG induced by completing the partial ordering on $G$ by expanding it from a node being reachable to a node being adjacent. More specifically, $G'$ is the graph with the same vertex set as $G$ where $a \to b$ is an edge of $G'$ if and only if there exists some path from $a$ to $b$ in $G$. So we are just adding the necessary edges to $G$ to make vertex adjacency transitive. Now we note that the indegree and outdegree of a node $x$ in $G'$ is exactly the number of ancestors and descendants respectively of the node $x$ in $G$. So thinking this way, you could refer to the number of ancestors or the number of descendants of a given node $x$ respectively as the **induced indegree** and the **induced outdegree** of $x$.
- Or of course you just be use a new word or term, like

  - ancestor-count and descendant-count
  - lesser-count and greater-count
  - the support of $x$ and the load of $x$
  - absolute indegree and absolute outdegree
  - total indegree and total outdegree