# Number of sink vertices connected to a vertex in a directed acyclic graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

I'm looking for a term in graph theory for the number of sink vertices (or end vertices) connected via a directed path to each vertex in a directed acyclic graph. I mocked up a sample network here, with this value inside each vertex:
[Sample DAG with count of sink vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPgM2.png).

I've been searching but have not been able to see any technical name for this. Terms that are close but don't quite capture the situation are *degree* (number of edges connected to a vertex) and *centrality* (influence of a vertex in a network). My question is similar to this one - [Name for Number of Ancestors/Descendants of Vertex in Directed Acyclic Graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868364/name-for-number-of-ancestors-descendants-of-vertex-in-directed-acyclic-graph) - just with the additional criteria that the count only includes those with an outdegree of 0.

If it is an unnamed term, do one of these sound particularly appropriate?

- sink/end/terminal centrality (stemming from the term *degree centrality*)
- sink/end/terminal degree

Thanks for any tips.